# How to set the default icon for apps in registry using Exe?

Tags: nsis

I created the installer using NSIS. Everything working fine but default 
    icon not setting to the particular files.

```
   WriteRegStr HKCR "Myapp\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\Myexe,1"
```

I need to set default icon by using my `Exe` not by using icon file

Comment: Post more code, it is impossible to diagnose this issue without further information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full path. If you want the first icon in your .exe then you don't need a icon index:

```
RequestExecutionLevel Admin

Section
WriteRegStr HKCR ".foo" "" "foofile" ; .foo file extension
WriteRegStr HKCR "foofile\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
SectionEnd
```

Other icons need a icon index:

```
WriteRegStr HKCR "MyProgId\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe,1"
```

Comment: Thank you sir.I already tried both types but still its not working.I tried this also (WriteRegStr HKCR "MyProgId\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\Ico.ico").But still its not working

Comment: There might be something else wrong. Is your application started correctly when you double-click your file-type?